# Auto Rotation iOS 8 Navigation Controller

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios8, uinavigationcontroller, autorotate

I have certain `viewControllers` which are managed by a `UINavigationController` (push and pop). I want to restrict different `viewControllers` to different `orientations` like the first one should be only in `Portrait`, second in `portrait`, third in `landscape` and fourth can be `portrait` and `landscape` both. I set a `ViewController` on `isInitialViewController` from `storyBoard`, the

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
return NO;
```

}

worked without any problem but when i set the `navigation controller` (managing these four views by push and pop) as `isInitialViewController` from `storyBoard`, this function stopped being called and now `autoratates`. How can I stop `autorotating` these views using this `UINavigationController` as the `isInitialViewController`. I use the following functions depends on which `ViewController` it is

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation{
return (interfaceOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationPortrait);//choose portrait or landscape}

- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate{
return NO;
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
//return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{ 
//    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft |
//    UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight;
return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just subclass UINavigationController and override appropriate methods:

.h File:

```
@interface CustomUINavigationController : UINavigationController
@property   BOOL canRotate;
@end
```

.m File:

```
@implementation CustomUINavigationController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}



- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return self.canRotate;
}
@end
```

Comment: Thanks,, The answer is correct but i just noticed by this that my scenario was a little bit different and so I implemented these functions in my SlideView and it worked.. Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

What if you make Objective C category for UINavigation Controller and Override interface orientation methods...I think u try to control the Autorotation.

Objective C category
http://rypress.com/tutorials/objective-c/categories

Comment: Very easy quickly go through it and implement ShouldAutorotate method, and try to control the autorotation.

Comment: develop a category for UINavigationController

Comment: Thanks for the idea but i just noticed that my scenario was a little bit different and so I implemented the functions in my SlideView and it worked.. Thanks a lot :)